# Concise formula for Skyrmion number of a four-band Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, skyrmion

[The Haldane model](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.2015) on the honeycomb lattice is often written as

$H=\sum_{i=0}^3 \vec{d}_i\cdot \vec{\sigma}_i$

where $\vec{\sigma}$ is the vector of Pauli matrices and $\vec{d}$ is a vector of coefficients of the Hamiltonian matrix. In this form, the Skyrmion number can then be computed as

$\Omega_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\hat{d}\cdot (\partial_i \hat{d}\times \partial_j \hat{d})$

However, the above formulation depends upon the system being a two-band model. For a four-band model, such as [the Kane-Mele model](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0411737), is there an equivalent formulation of the Skyrmion number in terms of a Pauli or Pauli-like decomposition of the Hamiltonian? I feel like this should be well-known, but I have not found anything in the literature which discusses such a formulation.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.  The space of self-adjoint $2\times 2$ matrices with complex entries is an $\mathbb R$-vector space of dimension $4$. Any two-band Hamiltonian can be put in the form $H_\mathbf k = \vec d(\mathbf k) \cdot \vec \sigma$ after subtraction of a term proportional to the identity matrix. If the gap $\Delta = 2|\vec d(\mathbf k)|$ never closes, then $\hat d := \vec d/|\vec d|$ constitutes a continuous map from the Brillouin zone to the 2-sphere $\mathrm S^2$.

Any continuous map between two closed (i.e. compact without boundary) manifolds of the same dimension has an associated topological invariant called its *degree*.  In 2D, the Brillouin zone is the 2-torus $\mathrm T^2$ which has the same dimension as $\mathrm S^2$, and the degree of $\hat d$ is the skyrmion number you reference; $\pm \mathrm{deg}(\hat d)$ is also equal to the Chern number of the conduction and valence bands, respectively.

The space of self-adjoint $4\times 4$ matrices with complex entries, on the other hand, is an $\mathbb R$-vector space of dimension 16; any decomposition of the Hamiltonian in terms of a basis of self-adjoint $4\times 4$ matrices is going to define a map to a much higher dimensional space.

Of course, one can still compute the Chern numbers of each band in a $4$-band model (as long as the bands don't cross, of course), which is what I would regard as the appropriate generalization of the skyrmion number you reference, but it won't take such a nice compact form in terms of the parameters of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you happen to know of any references which discuss the appropriate generalization of the skyrmion number for the 4-band model?

Also, couldn't there be some way to map certain 4x4 matrices to a 4D vector, assuming certain entries are zero?